# jQuery Mobile getting popout to open on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, pageload

I am using the new pop out features for JQM. Launching the popout via a button click is straightforward but how can I get the popout to launch on page load?

JQM docs say you can do initialise the popout via:

```
$( "#myPopupDiv" ).popup( "open" )
```

I tried this by using the code below but can't get it to work.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$( "#myPopupDiv" ).popup( "open" )
});
```

Here is a working demo using video in the popout and a button to launch it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fxakH/

If someone could help make this launch on page load it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Same problem here! Would be cool if you could tell me how this works... (if you solved it in the meantime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and googled a bit. I found that you asked the question on the jQuery-forum as well and got an answer:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/launching-popout-on-page-load
http://jsfiddle.net/fxakH/4/

For others with the same problem:
The key seems to be to open the popup during the `pageshow` event. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The "mobileinit" event fires immediately. Have you tried "[pageinit](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)"?

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
    $( "#myPopupDiv" ).popup( "open" )
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried it and it just shows the page loading wheel. "mobileinit" got the popup to launch on page load but i couldn't close it.

Comment: $(document).ready does not work either, results in a loading wheel too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried a method as follows.

The popup in my page was to be opened both on page load and on an anchor in the page

So in pageinit, I initialized the popup, and right after that statement, I triggered the click of the anchor which also opens the popup. That worked. here is the code.

```
//script to be called on add seat page
$( document ).delegate("#addseat-page", "pageinit", function() {
  $("#vipPopup").popup(); //vip popup
  $("#openvipPopup").trigger("click"); //openvipPopup is the id of the anchor for popup
});
```

Cheers.